# Short story about an artist who is forced by a demon to paint

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read the story in an anthology of fantasy and science fiction works in the late nineties, but it is possible that the story in question is considerably older than that. The plot centers around a young man who is a successful artist and his admirer, possibly female, who discovers in the end of the story that the artist works day and night driven by a small demon or devil. Having seen that, the admiration turns into pity.

Comment: Can you think of anything else that would help identify the story? I suggest reading [How to ask a good story-id question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is *[Unamusing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56483)* (1984) by Alan Dean Foster, the anthology was *[The Metrognome and Other Stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1549625.The_Metrognome_and_Other_Stories)* (1990).

I obviously did not research sufficiently before asking here. Sorry, I found the answer myself on the internet after it came to my mind that it could have been Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: That's the way it works sometimes. They call that Rubber Duck Debugging and I'm mildly notorious for doing it on here.